How do I fix the "No window was shown" error in uispecj4?
I've been trying to get tests running for my project but every time I run it it gives me an error
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        setAdapter(new MainClassAdapter(Login.class));

        Window window = getMainWindow();
    }

This is the code for my setup, it has an error when it tries to getMainWindow(). It's a maven project, the login class is setup and is running, here is the code that displays the window:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true); System.out.println("window showingg");
            }
        });
    }

Could anyone help me figure out what's going on? Thanks
